# Is it possible to define shortcuts in text mode

Tags: tex-general

I want to learn if it is possible to define some short cuts in text mode. For example instead of typing "topological vector space", "monotone convergence theorem" etc. each time in a text, is there a way to define a short cut for "topological vector space" in the preamble.

Comment: Yes. Use `\newcommand{\tvs}{Topological Vector Space}`. But note that you need to insert space after it. For example, `... \tvs\ is...`

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Yes, this is possible either with a `\def` approach or `\newcommand`... But this does not provide for grammatical changes in the context, e.g. a plural

Comment: I recommend using sparingly this feature: in a couple of months after you've finished writing your document you'll forget what the shortcuts mean, if they're more than a handful.